# Simulation of a simple scenario without accidents in Veins

Tags: omnet++

I installed Omnet ++ 4.6, Sumo 0.21.0 and Veins 3.0 to simulate vehicle mobility.

I read the existing tutorials of Omnet ++ as well as the documentation of Veins simulator but I'm really stuck. I spent two weeks to understand the source code but in vain.

I want to simulate a set of mobile vehicles that exchange information among themselves.
What do I need to change in the source code of the existing exemple?
I'm not interested in the scenario of accidents taking place between the cars. How can I modify the source code of the application to eliminate it?

Also is there a tutorial that explains the source code (TraCIDemo11p.cc and TraCIDemoRSU11p.cc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building on the example that comes with Veins version 4a2, there is nothing you need to change: vehicles will already be exchanging messages among themselves: in the example (if a vehicle has not yet sent a message) it sends a message [whenever a node stops](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4a2/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc#L94) and [whenever a message is received](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4a2/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc#L55).

If you don't want a particular node to stop (modeling an accident), do not set its [`accidentCount`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4a2/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIMobility.ned#L45) to a value higher than 0 ([as the example currently does for any node ending in "0"](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4a2/examples/veins/omnetpp.ini#L129)). Note that this will mean that there is no reason for nodes to exchange messages then, so you might want to implement a different trigger (maybe a triggering a predefined node at a predefined time).

Comment: Thank you for your reply Sir. 
I installed the version of Veins-4a2 as you told me the other day, but when I click on "Run As > OMNeT++ simulation", it displays an error and simulation will not start. In this case, I tried to erase the Veins-3.0 already installed under OMNeT ++ but in vain.
I uninstalled OMNeT ++ and I tried to do it all again, but this time the problem is that I got an error when I typed "make" in the " MinGW command" of OMNeT ++.
Is it not possible to import two versions of veins under OMNeT ++?

Comment: Yes, it is easier to install only one version.